# How does std::map's emplace() avoid premature construction?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, std, emplace

I am confused about `std::maps`'s implementation of `emplace()`. `emplace()` is a variadic template function with the following declaration:

```cpp
template <class Args...>
iterator emplace( Args&&... args );
```

As far as I understand, `emplace()` completely avoids constructing its `value_type`, i.e., `std::pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`, and instead constructs the object in-place. I assume this means that the object is constructed only once, the moment that the new map node is created. The object is never copied or moved.

What I don't understand is how `std::map` finds the correct place to add the new entry before constructing the key-value pair. As far as I see, `std::map` needs access to the key but the key is contained within `args` and only accessible after construction of the key-value pair.

I must be misunderstanding some aspect of `emplace()`. Does `std::map` actually avoid construction of the key-value pair? If so, how does it avoid move/copy operations? Or is there another way to access the key in `args`?

Comment: It constructs *the pair* in-place forwarding the arguments to its constructor. It does not avoid `element_type` construction, it just avoids one copy of a useless temporary pair compared to `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emplace` constructs the pair in-place forwarding the arguments to its constructor; it does not avoid `element_type` construction, it just avoids one copy of a useless temporary pair compared to `insert`. In this regard, it's just as for the other containers: `emplace` is like `insert`, but instead if receiving a ready-made `element_type` to copy or move inside the container, it receives the arguments to construct `element_type` in its target location.

To further clarify: if you call `emplace(key, value)` `key` and `value` *are* copied/moved anyhow when constructing the pair. It's just that, if you did `insert(make_pair(key, value))`, not only `key` and `value` would have beem copied/moved when creating the temporary pair argument, but the pair itself would have then needed to be moved in the map node.

> I don't think that is what OP intends to ask for. The intended question to me seems to be how `std::map` can find the correct location to insert the new element if it can't construct the key prior to searching for the location, e.g. if the first argument to `emplace` is not the key type itself.

In that case for an `std::map` there's not much of a problem: first you can construct a node (which contains the pair and the various pointers to other nodes, and has its own allocation on the heap), and then you can put it in the right place in the RB tree (which boils down to just a couple of pointers assignment).

Comment: I don't think that is what OP intends to ask for. The intended question to me seems to be how `std::map` can find the correct location to insert the new element if it can't construct the key prior to searching for the location, e.g. if the first argument to `emplace` is not the key type itself.

Comment: In that case for an std::map there's not much of a problem: first you can construct a node (which has its own allocation on the heap), and then you can put it in the right place in the RB tree (which boils down to just a couple of pointers assignment).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Your comment is the answer I was looking for. I got so stuck thinking about how to avoid constructing the value pair, that I didn't even consider just constructing the node. Thank you!

Comment: @chiasmos: great, I'll move it into the answer body! Sorry I didn't understand that from the start.

Comment: And then if it is determined that insertion is not possible, the node is destroyed again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IIRC, `std::map` and `std::unrodered_map` use tree-like structures, with a lot of small nodes pointing at each other. So once the pair is constructed - it doesn't have to be moved anywhere, the map simply needs to point at it from somewhere.